# Axios POSt return statusText unknow

Tags: reactjs, express

When I make an Axios.post it work correctly but the response.statustext is unknown instead of  **OK** as response.status is 209
how can i fix the problem?  I'm using reactjs and express API

```
const Survey = async (label) => {
  let response = await Axios.post('/api/survey', {
    label
  })
  console.log(`response.statusText`, response)
  if (response.statusText === 'OK')
    return response.data
  else
    throw response.data
`}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just check if the status code is 200 or 209?

```
const Survey = async (label) => {
  let response = await Axios.post('/api/survey', {
    label
  });

  if (response.status === 200) // 200 or 209 or whatever
    return response.data
  else
    throw response.data // shouldn't this be an new Error()?
`}
```

If you want to programatically set statusText on the frontend, regardless of what the backend returns, then you can use an axios interceptor: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

The example in the link above shows that the `response.use` function takes 2 callback functions, one for 200 status responses and one for all others. you can do whatever you want with the response in those functions, like append your own custom code:

`response.myCustomStatus = "Okey Dokey";`

Hope that helps!

Comment: do you know a quick way to make statustext to be set automatically according to the statuscode,. as if you write only api callyou dont habve to know status code set by the one who wrote the api route

Comment: I updated my response. Axios interceptors are probably what you wanna use